# Get application-default service account email in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I have some code in a Cloud Run-hosted service which sends a scheduled request back to itself via Cloud Tasks. As with all Google java libraries, the cloud tasks library quite happily authenticates via the application default credentials provided via Cloud Run.

However, in order for the scheduled request to then authenticate, I'd need to configure the authentication in the request back to the endpoint that is requested via cloud tasks, the cloud tasks SDK provides such a facility, like in the example below.

```
           // Construct the task body.
           Task.Builder taskBuilder = Task.newBuilder()
                    .setHttpRequest(
                             HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                      .setUrl( endpoint )
                                      .setHttpMethod( HttpMethod.GET )
                                      .setOidcToken( OidcToken.newBuilder()
                                               .setServiceAccountEmail( requestServiceAccountEmail )
                                               .setAudience( audience ).build() )
                                      .build() )
                    .setScheduleTime( Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds( taskTime.getEpochSecond() ) );

           // Send create task request.
           client.createTask( queuePath, taskBuilder.build() );
```

This works perfectly, however its having to specify `requestServiceAccountEmail` means I need to pass in the service account email via an environment variable or via application config, which feels a but un-neccesary as we can get the credentials for most services via the application-default credentials.

Is there a better method to authenticate the request here, or at the a convenient method to determine the current service-account email that the service is running as via the google cloud auth library?

I've checked the `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()` API which doesn't appear to provide the email address of the default credentials.